# Apache Components and Spring Boot

Tags: apache, gradle, spring-boot, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to include the latest version of the apache httpclient libraries in my spring boot application.  When I try to compile the app I get a bunch of package does not exist / cannot find symbol.

```
ex.  error: package org.apache.http does not exist
ex.  error: package org.apache.http.client.config does not exist
ex.  error: package org.apache.http.conn.socket does not exist
ex.  class HttpContext cannot find symbol
```

Below are the relevant parts of my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
//excluding a particular transitive dependency:
exclude group: 'commons-logging' //by group
exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback' //by group
}

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Any idea why id doesn't seem to be able to find the classes?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Are you trying to build in CLI or IDE?

Comment: CLI, I am running gradlew clean build

Comment: do you see those dependencies being pulled if you run with "--refresh-dependencies"??